# Loop Pandas DF to append new lines to txt

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have flat file (txt), in which I have Date column and Value column.

I am trying to append new lines to the txt in case my dataframe receives new lines, using a loop logic. I have this following code:
LastDate I am saying here its equal to 0 for simplicity reasons.

```
LastDate = 0
saveFileLine = name+'.txt.'
saveFile = open(saveFileLine,'a')

for index, row in namedf.iterrows():
    if int(''.join(row['Date'].split('-')[:3])) > LastDate:
        lineToWrite = row+'\n'
        saveFile.write(lineToWrite)

saveFile.close()
```

and it gives me the error:

**write() argument must be str, not Series**

I dont know how to make it write the line of the loop currently active.

Hope you can help me out!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each row is a Pandas Series. You're treating the whole row as a string. Do you want to write the whole row?

```
for index, row in namedf.iterrows():
    lineToWrite = row.to_string()
    saveFile.write(lineToWrite)
```

Comment: Yes, I want to write the whole row, which is the values of two columns.
This still gives me the same error
write() argument must be str, not Series

Comment: Modified answer following your comment.

Comment: Hey xpqz, thanks! It is printing now, just the output of how its being printed is not what I want, its printing like this:

Date 2016-02-29
Value 70
Date 2016-02-30
Value 75

Any idea why? I want: Date and Value and then the values of both underneath

Comment: I think you can probably work that out yourself -- check the docs for pandas.Series. You can for instance convert the row to a normal dict, like

   rowDict = row.to_dict()

and have full control over how you choose to save this to your file. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html

Comment: I think I will try the angle of converting to a numpy array.. Got to run now, will check that later as well, thanks!